# How to pass single quotes and single quote into string variable in Ansible

Tags: ansible, yaml

I'm fairly new to YML and Ansible, however I've been tasked to do some automation for my work.
I have a string variable that need to have double and single quote inside:

```
-d 'request=("folder":"Testing_it","attributes":{})'
```

So I've have written quickly a simple play with that would check if it works:

```
- name: Assign variable
set_fact:
  params: " -d 'request=(\"folder\":\"Testing_it\",\"attributes\":{})'"

- name: Show output
debug:
  msg: "{{ params }}"
```

I wanted to see how my variable look before continuing and this is output from Ansible:

```
    ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": " -d 'request=(\"folder\":\"Testing_it\",\"attributes\":{})'"
}
```

Why does the backslash is included in that variable ? Can somebody help me how should I properly code that to get it working as intended

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to escape the single quotes, only the double quotes you should escape them with backslash `\`

to make sure your `params` variable is properly set, you can output them to a file and see the content:

```
- name: Save output
  copy: content="{{ params }}" dest=/path/to/destination/file
```